# Create a function that can handle both list or symbol as input argument

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I've created a function, select_or_return , that should handle both column symbols and lists as input arguments. When providing it with a column symbol, it works as expected. However, when I provide a list, I encounter an error related to the ensym() function from the rlang package.

How could I create a function that can handle both a list or symbol as input argument?

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

select_or_return <- function(data, x) {

x_sym <- ensym(x)

  # If x is a symbol
  if (is_symbol(x_sym)) {
     return(data %>% select(!!x_sym))
  } 
  # If x is a list
  else if (is.list(x)) {
    return(x)
  } 
  # For other cases
  else {
    stop("x must be a symbol representing a column or a list.")
  }
}

# Example usage:

# Create a sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

# Use the function with a column name as a symbol
print(select_or_return(df, a))
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 4
#> 5 5

# Use the function with a list
print(select_or_return(df, list(1,2,3)))
#> Error in `ensym()`:
#> ! Can't convert to a symbol.
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─base::print(select_or_return(df, list(1, 2, 3)))
#>  2. ├─global select_or_return(df, list(1, 2, 3))
#>  3. │ └─rlang::ensym(x)
#>  4. └─rlang::abort(message = message)
```

Comment: It looks like rlang::ensym() in your function, regardless of argument x as a symbol or list, tries to convert argument x to symbol, and it comes before your if else code.

Comment: @knitz3 Even if you evaluate x directly without using ensym(x) you will get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used inside your own function, the rlang functions `ensym` and `enexpr` are superficially similar to base R's `substitute` (which they both use internally). When they are passed one of your own function's arguments, they substitute it for the *defused* R code that was passed to that argument. Here, *defused* means that the expression has been parsed successfully, but not yet evaluated. We can see the similarity between the three functions if we do:

```r
f <- function(x) list(substitute(x), rlang::enexpr(x), rlang::ensym(x))

f(hello)
#> [[1]]
#> hello
#> 
#> #> [[2]]
#> hello
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> hello
```

The behaviour of `enxpr` and `ensym` are a little different from `substitute`, in that they both only accept a single symbol as an argument, whereas `substitute` accepts arbitrary expressions. That isn't important in this particular scenario.

What *is* important is the difference between `ensym` on the one hand and `enexpr` and `substitute` on the other. Specifically, `ensym`, does not permit *expressions* such as `list(1, 2, 3)`. This is done on purpose, to ensure that the output of `ensym` is guaranteed to be a symbol. From the docs:

> - ensym() and ensyms() are like enexpr() and enexprs() but they throw an error when the defused expressions are not simple symbols.

You are getting an error when you call `select_or_return(df, list(1,2,3))` because you are trying to pass the *expression* `list(1,2,3)` to `ensym`.

The more general rlang function for capturing symbols *or* expressions is `enexpr`. However, this too will capture anything passed to `x` in *unevaluated* form. You cannot test whether `x` is a list after it has been captured by `enexpr` unless you first evaluate it, because unevaluated code cannot be a list - it can only be an unevaluated bit of code.

Whilst you *could* write this function using `enexpr`, perhaps as simply as `function(data, x) eval_tidy(enexpr(x), data)`, this will return your column as a vector, and if you pass a symbol that is not a column in your data frame but exists somewhere else on the search path, it will be returned without error. This may not be your intention.

It may therefore be easiest to do the whole thing in base R:

```r
select_or_return <- function(data, x) {
  
  x_nm <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if(x_nm %in% names(data)) return(data[x_nm])
  if(is.symbol(substitute(x)) & !exists(x_nm)) {
    stop("x must be a symbol representing a column, or a list.")
  }
  if(is.list(x)) return(x)
  stop("x must be a symbol representing a column, or a list.")
}
```

Testing, we get:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

select_or_return(df, a)
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 4
#> 5 5

select_or_return(df, list(1,2,3))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
```

And if we pass a symbol that doesn't represent a column in the data frame or a list in the calling environment, we get our own specific error message.

```r
select_or_return(df, d)
#> Error in select_or_return(df, d): x must be a symbol representing a column, or a list.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! but what if I want to use this function inside another one? wrapper_func <- function(data, x){ select_or_return(data, x)}? Then I again get the error: x must be a symbol representing a column, or a list.

Comment: @Nivel In this scenario you might be better using quosures, since you need to pass around the appropriate evaluation frame, which is what quosures do (they are a list-like object containing an unevaluated expressions plus the environment in which the expression should be evaluated). However, `wrapper_func <- function(data, x) do.call(select_or_return, list(data = data, x = substitute(x)))` would also do the trick.